# await population of a stream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, resharper, async-await

In my MVC controller, i have an action that will populate a stream which i will use later:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> BuildFileContent(FileParameters fileParams)
{
    byte[] output;
    if (fileParams != null)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await Task.Run(() => PopulateFile(fileParams, stream)); // Here i populate the stream
            stream.Flush();
            output = stream.ToArray();
        }
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        FileContents.Add(guid, output); // just save the content for later use
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Value = guid });
    }

    return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid parameters");
}
```

I had this problem because ReSharper is giving out a warning: `access on disposed closure` on the line `PopulateFile(fileParams, stream)` and pointing out `stream`.

I have searched for the meaning of it and it seems that it warns that i could possibly use an already disposed stream.

I want to await the population of the stream because the task could take long.

Is there a way that I can wait the population of the stream without ReSharper giving this warning?
Moreover, i am calling `stream` inside the `using` clause, the stream should not yet be disposed until i call flush or the last line of the using clause is executed right? So why does ReSharper warn about accessing a disposed stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resharper warns you because you are using the stream inside a lambda expression that can basically be run whenever and not just inside the `using` scope.
If this was your code you could dispose of the stream before the task ended and you would have a `ObjectDisposedException` on your hands:

```
Task task = null;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
   task = Task.Run(() => PopulateFile(fileParams, stream)); // Here i populate the stream
   stream.Flush();
   output = stream.ToArray();
}
await task;
```

In your case however you **`await`** that operation and dispose the stream only after that operation has finished. So basically you are in the clear, but Resharper evidently doesn't know that.

To clear the warning altogether you can put the `using` scope inside the task:

```
await Task.Run(() => 
{
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         PopulateFile(fileParams, stream);
         stream.Flush();
         output = stream.ToArray();
     }
});
```

And I recommend you do.

Comment: Another option is to simply remove the `using`, since `MemoryStream` doesn't actually hold any resources that need disposing.

Answer (score 1):

@I3arnon's answer is completely correct, but I wanted to address one important point.

> I want to await the population of the stream because the task could take long.

That is a noble goal, but benefiting from `await` depends entirely on your implementation of `PopulateFile`, which presumably is not an async method, judging by how it is called. Anytime you do something like `await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingSynchronously())`, you are gaining nothing in terms of freeing up threads.

I would suggest taking a close look at PopulateFile, determine where the slowness is coming from, and see if you can leverage any truly asynchronous APIs for things like [Web access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx), [file I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx), etc. If you can rewrite PopulateFile into an async method (i.e. with a signature like `async Task PopulateFileAsync(...)`) that leverages those APIs, you'll have something that truly frees up threads while waiting on long-running operations, and you can await it directly, without `Task.Run`:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await PopulateFileAsync(fileParams, stream)); // Here i populate the stream
    stream.Flush();
    output = stream.ToArray();
}
```

And as a bonus, the above code shouldn't elicit complaints from R#.